# Can't Make a Player Two

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a second player to javascript game but the code isn't working. I need some instruction on how to follow through with this. The second player doesn't need to be fancy, a different color square would suffice. My current player is the green square. Any information would be helpful thank you.

```js
var myObstacle;
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();
function startGame() {}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 700,
    height =600,
    player = {
      x : 1,
      y : 7,
      width : 25,
      height : 25,
      speed: 10,
      velX: 0,
      velY: 0,
      jumping: false
    },
    keys = [],
    friction = .9,
    gravity = .8;
 
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update(){
  // check keys
    if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
        // up arrow or space
      if(!player.jumping){
       player.jumping = true;
       player.velY = -player.speed*.1;
      }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {             
            player.velX++;         
         }     
    }     
    if (keys[37]) {         
        // left arrow         
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }
 
    player.velX *= friction;
 
    player.velY += gravity;
 
    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;
 
    if (player.x >= width-player.width) {
        player.x = width-player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {         
        player.x = 0;     
    }    
  
    if(player.y >= height-player.height){
        player.y = height - player.height;
        player.jumping = false;
    }
 
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
 
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
 
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
 
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
 
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    update();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Square Stairs™</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000">
 <canvas id="canvas" style="border:3px solid #fff"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help if you can, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use a little bit of OOP:

```js
var myObstacle;
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

function Player(color){
  this.x =  1;
  this.y = 7
  this.width = 25
  this.height= 25
  this.speed= 10
  this.velX= 0
  this.velY= 0
  this.jumping= false
  this.color = color;
}

function startGame() {}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 700,
    height =600,
    player = new Player('green'),
    player2 = new Player('red')
    keys = [],
    friction = .9,
    gravity = .8;
 
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update(){
  // check keys
    if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
        // up arrow or space
      if(!player.jumping){
       player.jumping = true;
       player.velY = -player.speed*.1;
      }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {             
            player.velX++;         
         }     
    }     
    if (keys[37]) {         
        // left arrow         
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }
 
    player.velX *= friction;
 
    player.velY += gravity;
 
    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;
 
    if (player.x >= width-player.width) {
        player.x = width-player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {         
        player.x = 0;     
    }    
  
    if(player.y >= height-player.height){
        player.y = height - player.height;
        player.jumping = false;
    }
    
    
    player2.velY += gravity;
 
    player2.x += player2.velX;
    player2.y += player2.velY;
 
    if (player2.x >= width-player2.width) {
        player2.x = width-player2.width;
    } else if (player2.x <= 0) {         
        player2.x = 0;     
    }    
  
    if(player2.y >= height-player2.height){
        player2.y = height - player2.height;
        player2.jumping = false;
    }
 
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = player2.color;
  ctx.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
 
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
 
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
 
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    update();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Square Stairs™</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000">
 <canvas id="canvas" style="border:3px solid #fff"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo Dawg yo the real MVP!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I couldn't resist... I added even more OOP. So, now you can add as many players as you'd like. The important distinction is the color and the key mappings. My example (arbitrarily) adds three players:

```
var players=[];
players.push(new Player('green', {
   32: 'jump',
   37: 'left',
   38: 'jump',
   39: 'right'
}))
players.push(new Player('red', {
   56: 'jump',
   52: 'left',
   54: 'right'
}, width-25))
players.push(new Player('blue', {
   87: 'jump',
   65: 'left',
   68: 'right'
}, (width-25)/2))
```

```js
var myObstacle;
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();
function startGame() {}

function Player(color,keymap,x) {
   this.x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? 1 : x;
   this.y = 7;
   this.width  = 25;
   this.height = 25;
   this.speed  = 10;
   this.velX   = 0;
   this.velY   = 0;
   this.jumping= false;

   this.keymap = {}
   for (let key in keymap) {
      switch (keymap[key]) {
         case 'jump':
            this.keymap[key] = this.jump
            break;
         case 'left':
            this.keymap[key] = this.moveLeft
            break;
         case 'right':
            this.keymap[key] = this.moveRight
            break;
      }
   }
   this.color  = color;
} // Player()

Player.prototype.jump=function () {
   if (!this.jumping) {
    this.jumping = true;
    this.velY = -this.speed*1.5;
   }
}
Player.prototype.moveRight = function () {
   if (this.velX < this.speed) {
       this.velX++;
    }
}
Player.prototype.moveLeft = function () {
   if (this.velX > -this.speed) {
       this.velX--;
   }
}
// Globals
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 700,
    height =600,
    keys = [],
    friction = .9,
    gravity = .8;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Set up players
var players=[];
players.push(new Player('green', {
   32: 'jump',
   37: 'left',
   38: 'jump',
   39: 'right'
}))
players.push(new Player('red', {
   56: 'jump',
   52: 'left',
   54: 'right'
}, width-25))
players.push(new Player('blue', {
   87: 'jump',
   65: 'left',
   68: 'right'
}, (width-25)/2))

function update() {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
   players.forEach(player => {
      // check player-specific keys
      for (let i in player.keymap)
      {
         if (keys[i] && typeof player.keymap[i] === 'function')
            player.keymap[i].bind(player)();
      }

      player.velX *= friction;

      player.velY += gravity;

      player.x += player.velX;
      player.y += player.velY;

      if (player.x >= width-player.width) {
         player.x = width-player.width;
      } else if (player.x <= 0) {
         player.x = 0;
      }

      if (player.y >= height-player.height) {
         player.y = height - player.height;
         player.jumping = false;
      }

      ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
      ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
   }) // player.forEach
   requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
//  console.log(e.keyCode);
   keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
   keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    update();
});
```

```html
html>
<head>
    <title>Square Stairs™</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000">
 <canvas id="canvas" style="border:3px solid #fff"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```